# Securing restful api calls

Tags: java, angularjs, api

I have an application developed using **AngularJS** for front end and **Java** for back end.

issue i am facing is, if the user logs in to the application and searches for a particular data, there will be an API call with payload **JSON** sent to the server, in response we will get the data in JSON related to search parameters.

Problem here is user can open developer tool and copy the URL of the API and JSON payload and post the same data in **Postman** or **DHC client** and get the response JSON and more over he can alter data related to role and get search results that are related to other role/users.

My question is how to protect the API from directly calling form other sources and altering the payload.

Comment: You can use kind of some key mechanism, if it is available in payload then only you'll serve request otherwise not. You can use OAuth also for this.

Comment: @user3145373ツ If its static payload. what suppose, if he finds and add it in header?

Answer (score 1):

There is no fundamental difference between requests sent by JavaScript client app by your browser and requests sent "manually" from any other tool like Postman or whatever. There is generally no security issue until all your requests are protected by any authentication mechanism like OAuth or simply with some secret API keys passed with each request (in this case these API keys should belong to the particular authenticated user only!).

Keep in mind, that security layer which protects your system from malicious or unsecured operations should lie on the **server side** only, not on client app. That means that everything which can be done from client app by a particular user can be done from any other tool (as you mentioned above) in "manual" mode by the same user.